# Improper integrals, a question from real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Discuss the convergence of
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$ 
Guys , I know mu-test , comparison test, But here I am unable to understand which test to use and how to discuss the convergence of the given integral.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the substitution $u = \dfrac{1}{x}$

$$\int_0^1 \dfrac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}} dx = -\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{\log u}{u^{3/2}} du$$

Eventually $\log{u}\le \sqrt[3]{u}$. So there is a $C>1$ such that

$$\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{\log u}{u^{3/2}} du <  \int_1^{C} \dfrac{\log u}{u^{3/2}} du + \int_C^{\infty} \dfrac{u^{1/3}}{u^{3/2}} du$$

The last integral above converges (elementary calculus). Therefore so does the original.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate by parts:
$$
\int\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=
2\sqrt{x}\,\log x-\int 2\sqrt{x}\frac{1}{x}\,dx
$$

Answer (score 0):

The integrand is continuous on $]0,1]$ so its antiderivative there is valid: (Obtained using integration by parts)
$$ \int \frac{\log x}{\sqrt x} \mathrm dx = 2\sqrt{x}(\log x - 2)
$$
Since
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\log x}{\sqrt x} \mathrm dx = \lim_{r \searrow 0} \int_r^1 \frac{\log x}{\sqrt x} \mathrm dx
$$
The question reduces to whether the limit $\lim_{x \searrow 0} \sqrt{x} \log x$ exist, which it does using l'Hopital.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a substitution to take rid of the logarithm: $y=\log x$. Then $$\int_0^1 \frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}} dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\epsilon}^1 \frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}} = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\log \epsilon}^0 \frac{y}{e^{y/2}}e^y dy = \lim_{M \to -\infty} \int^0_M y e^{y/2}dy = \lim_{M \to -\infty} \bigg([2ye^{y/2}]^{0}_{M} - 2 \int^0_Me^{y/2}dy \bigg) = \lim_{M \to -\infty} [-4e^{y/2}]^0_M = -4$$

Answer (score 0):

A positive power of $x$ always wins over $\ln x$ as $x\to 0^+.$ In other words, for any $p>0,$ $\lim_{x\to 0^+} x^p\ln x =0.$ It follows that

$$\frac{|\ln x|}{x^{1/2}} = \frac{x^{1/4}|\ln x|}{x^{3/4}} \le \frac{1}{x^{3/4}}$$

for small $x>0.$ Since $\int_0^1 (1/x^{3/4})\, dx < \infty,$ your integral is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 0):

With the change of variable $x=e^{-t}$ we get, for any $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$,
$$ \int_{\varepsilon}^{1}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx = \int_{0}^{-\log\varepsilon}t e^{-t/2}\,dt = 4\int_{0}^{-\frac{\log\varepsilon}{2}}ue^{-u}\,du = \left. 4(u+1)e^{-u}\right|_{0}^{-\frac{\log\varepsilon}{2}}$$
hence:
$$ \int_{\varepsilon}^{1}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx = -4+4\sqrt{\varepsilon}\left(1-\tfrac{1}{2}\log\varepsilon\right) $$
and since $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\sqrt{\varepsilon}\log\varepsilon = 0$,
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx = \color{red}{-4}.$$